# How to run Google Embed API Server-side Authorization with PHP?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to run the Google Embed API Server-side Authorization demo, here: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/, but using PHP instead of Python for Step 3 (Using the JSON key data to request an access token).

I have installed the Google API PHP client: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.

I have created a Service Account (https://console.developers.google.com), enabled Analytics API for it, downloaded the JSON key file, and copied that to my web server (below web root level for security).

I have registered the Service Account in the Google Analytics account (read & analyse only).

I am trying to run the demo using replacement PHP code from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32767845/1803239:

```
<?php    

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Create the client object and set the authorization configuration
// from the client_secretes.json you downloaded from the developer console.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('/path/to/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);


// If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
// else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  // Set the access token on the client.
   $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

  // Create an authorized analytics service object.
  $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);


  // Get the results from the Core Reporting API and print the results.

} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}


//get the access token
$myToken = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
?>
```

Running the demo (in a file named test3.php, with the PHP code instead of the Python code) fails at this line,
`$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');`,
with the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message
>   'Invalid client secret JSON file.' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php:171
>   Stack trace:
>
> #0 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php(189):
>   Google_Client->setAuthConfig('{? "type": "se...')
>
> #1 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/test3.php(36): Google_Client->setAuthConfigFile('/var/www/vhosts...')
>
> #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php
>   on line 171

Can anyone suggest why my JSON key file might be failing?

Update: OK, I have been trying to get this working for 5 days now. Maybe it can work, but my faith in Google's documentation is bust. Google, if you're reading this, please sort out your docs, they are sloppy in the extreme. Test them out on people.

If anyone can provide a working example of the API Server-side Authorization demo (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/), but using PHP instead of Python for Step 3, I will be eternally grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Because you are feeding it a service account jSon file and not an Oauth2 json file.  Your code is for Oauth2 not service account.

Comment: The demo instructions do say "Step 1: Create a service account and download the JSON key". Could they be wrong, or am I using the wrong PHP code here?

Comment: You are using the wrong php code.  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts

Comment: Thanks @DalmTo. OK, this page appears to be looking for P12 key files as opposed to JSON. I tried the code, up to this line,

$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

but with my JSON keyfile and it generates this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Unable to load private key' in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Signer/P12.php:70

Comment: I could generate a P12 file, but that's not what the original demo asks for...

Comment: Tried it with a P12 file instead of JSON, error result as follows. I am obviously missing something else here...

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'' in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php:364 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php(315): Google_Auth_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array) #1 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/test4.php(38): Google_Auth_OAuth2->refreshTokenWithAssertion() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php on line 364

Comment: hey man did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 4):

here is how I ended up doing this

```
$scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly';
$jsonKey = json_decode('[json file content here]', true);
// OR json key file path
// $jsonKeyFilePath = '/full/path/to/service-account.json';

$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setScopes([$scope]);
$client->setAuthConfig($jsonKey);

// OR use json file
// $client->setAuthConfigFile($jsonKeyFilePath);

$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();

echo $client->getAccessToken();
```

In google api client v2 there were some updates
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md

that as of Sep 2016 are not yet updated in the docs (which contains howto for v1)
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts